# Filter records by key - PigLatin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm starting to get into PigLatin and I have a question...

Right now I'm working with the classic example of word counting, where I process several e-books and then I get the list of words and the number of times each word appears.

Using that data as input data for pig, I then sort it by the number of times each word appears and I get the 5 most common words. So far so good, my problem though, is that now I want to get the 5 most common words but that appear different number of times. Let me explain a bit better:

Imagine this output to the word-count job:

```
(hey, 1)
(hello, 10)
(my, 2)
(cat, 1)
(eat, 4)
(mom, 10)
(house, 10)
```

I then do the following on the Grunt shell:

```
data = load 'file' as (word, freq);
srtd = order data by freq;
lmtd = limit srtd 3;
dump lmtd;
```

The output I'd get is:

```
(hello, 10)
(mom, 10)
(house, 10)
```

But what if I wanted to get this:

```
(hello, 10)
(eat, 4)
(my, 2)
```

How would I filter out repeated freq values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a UDF to do this maybe a little faster MR wise, but you could try one of these.

```
data = load 'file' as (word, freq);
counts = GROUP data BY freq;
countsLimited = FOREACH counts {
    word = TOP(1, 2, data);
    GENERATE FLATTEN(word);
}
```

or

```
data = load 'file' as (word, freq);
counts = GROUP data BY freq;
countsLimited = FOREACH counts {
    word = LIMIT data 1;
    GENERATE word;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, second example works, but I don't understand why, could your please elaborate a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: The GroupBy is producing a dataset that is grouping all words by their Freq. The output of which produces a set of rows containing a Bag of Tuples each. ie {(word,freq),(word,freq)}. Then the subsequent FOREACH loops of each row(Bag). The {} or Nested Block allows us to apply a special set of procedures to each row. This is only useful when each row is a collection of data ie a Bag. The alias "data" that we use within the block comes from the alias we used in the GroupBy. Which represents each bag we are working on.